# Google Appmaker: Update form based on selected dropdown option

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an AppMaker app that has a from based off of one address table/datasource.  I can get a form with next/prev buttons, but replaced the key field (name) with a dropdown list of all names *(a user can start typing names to jump there, with the dropdown showing)*.

My hope is that when a user selects from the dropdown, the entire form updates and the next/prev buttons work properly as well *(there too many records to page thru with next/prev only)*.  I don't have to have next/prev functionality if it complicates things too much.

Currently the dropdown is working, but I cannot get the index for the next/prev buttons set or the rest of the form to reflect the selected dropdown record.

I've tried to set the "onValueEdit" event to something like this...

```
var selected = widget.value;
var idx      = widget.options.indexOf(selected);

console.log("Selected: "+selected+", index = "+idx+"\n");
if(idx < 0) {                      //...this error is never hit
  console.log("Index error - setting to zero!\n");
  idx = 0;
}
widget.datasource.loadPage(idx);   //...update form?
```

Two observations via console logging:

1. The "idx" var is never set to the selected dropdown index reliably, and is
   often "0" *(tho no error msg ever shows)*, so the "indexOf()" function 
   isn't working as expected.
2. The "selected" var (name) is always correct.

If I call widget.datasource.loadPage(...) with a fixed value (say 5) it has no effect on what is shows in the form either *(previous loaded data remains)* - obviously not the way to do it :v/

Can you steer a *noob* in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** 
It's important that *Options* and *Value* are set as shown in the image below!

[image: AppMaker Dropdown Settings]

However, **I had trouble setting them that way** *(read: wasted hours!)* until I wiped them both completely using *More options* in the binding picklist, and tried again (I had even tried on a brand new app!). I was being forced to choose *..projections..* and then a final field before the **OK** button would be available.

Not sure if AppMaker is buggy here or there is something simple I'm not understanding!

None of the coding in my original question is required.
Once set this way, binding just works as you would expect it!!
All other fields are set as *@datasource.item.* and are bound to whatever item is chosen.  No *Events* settings are necessary for the dropdown either, as I thought they might be.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default App Maker form, then you can see that so-called `pager`, doesn't actually paginate. It triggers prevItem/nextItem datasource methods, in other words it navigates through datasource items, not pages. Here is a quote from App Maker docs:

> **nextItem:** Selects the next item. For Query Datasources, if the current item is the last item on the page, then this loads the next page and selects the first item on the newly loaded page.

So, if you already have all your items loaded(you set `query page size` for your datasource to 0), then you need just to change selected item within datasource:

```js
// onValueEdit dropdown event 
// assuming, that form and dropdown share same datasource
widget.datasource.selectKey(newValue._key);
```

If you really have lots of items and it is not feasible to load all of them in one call... then it will be all another story...

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  I have page size set to zero.  Form and dropdown are the same data.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: UPDATE: (I have just over 500 records) So there is no member "_key" for newValue, but .valueOf() returns the text of the name selected.  However, this still doesn't update the rest of the form.  Is there an api call for that maybe or will I have to update each form field manually?

Comment: Most likely you have your dropdown's `options` property bound to some field(`string` type), but not to the records themselves, that is why your `newValue` parameter is not of record type. Try this binding for your `options`: `@datasources.MyDatasource.items`

Comment: Just got back to this after some holidays @Pavel...

So I've had to use "... Projections -> BusinessName" to have the list work. Using what you've suggests only fills in one item in the dropdown, not all records?!

Comment: OK, so I changed it to a query, and that populates all values as well.  So I currently have the dropdown values set as "@datasource.query.filters.BusinessName._equals"

Comment: There are really only one thing I need to accomplish:

Have the form data update when I pick from the drop down, just like when I use the pager. I have decided i don't want to use the pager at all, only the drop down. 

I can get the drop-down to populate and even select an item, but the rest of the form data does not update. It stays to whatever record was last chosen by the pager.

I can get the drop-down to populate either with a query or choosing a 'projected' data item. Neither triggers updates to the form. 

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this page and started again, and replaced the default business name data field with a drop down, I set the dropdown as:

```
Options: @datasources.Addresses.items 

Value: @datasources.Addresses.item
```

It works fine?!  Not sure what happend in my original page!

**UPDATE:** 
So it seems you need to delete both the Value and Options and then re-enter these.  The OK will light up when you do.

Also, my original take on App Maker was to build the UI and attach data. That was my first mistake.  You build the data then have App Maker build edit/add pages for you.